# Как на PHP+GD нарисовать изогнутый текст (по дуге)

Tags: php, текст, gd, обработка-изображений

Всем доброго времени суток!

Задача: генерить в PHP с помощью GD текст, изогнутый по дуге с определенным углом, поверх заданного изображения.

Пример можно увидеть [здесь](http://www.ijfbacknumber.com/termek1.html). Вводим First name и Surname и видим результат.
Искал в и-нете и ничего по теме не нашел.

Вопрос: Как просчитать генерацию текста в подобном исполнении? Может есть более удобное решение или подскажите в хотя бы какую сторону копать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот что нашел:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33052404/how-to-create-curved-text-with-php-imagick

Правда они используют imagick создать картинку при наложении на другую ее искривить по дуге.

Как второй вариант (более гибкий) они предлагают создать SVG где любой текст можно искревить по любому пути.

```
<textPath xlink:href="#YourPath">Some Text</textPath>
```

и конвертировать в растр

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29563757/pdf-creation-with-an-svg-with-curved-text-in-php-no-text-is-shown

Comment: Спасибо! После некоторых испытаний решил остановиться на первом варианте.
Вывод: Моя проблема не в неумении искать, а в незнании инглиша =)